# Solving Complex Analysis Gamelin

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose complex valued $h(z)$ is harmonic on star-shaped domain $D$. I want to prove that there exists complex valued analytic functions

$f, g$ such that $h=f+\bar g$

This is my approach.

Since $h$ is harmonic, then by writing $u+iv:=h$,

$u, v$ are also harmonic, so we can find harmonic conjugate $u_1, v_1$ of $u, v$, respectively.

By defining $f=(u+iu_1)+i(v+iv_1), g:=v_1+iu_1$,

we can check $f$ is obviously analytic, and $h=f+\bar g$. So I only need to check $g$ is analytic.
But I could not go ahead. Could I get some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simpler. $\Re h$ is harmonic so we can write $\Re h=\frac {F+\overline F }2$ for some analytic function $F$. Simailrly, $\Im h=\frac {G+\overline G }2$ for some analytic function $G$. Now $h=\Re h+i\Im h$.  Can you see that this has the desired form?